# How to make Safari display forms on web pages correctly

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, web-browser, websites

In Safari, it is often the case that web-form show up in such a way that the text doesn't fit. Safari then inserts "..." in the text box (or combo-box, as the case may be). This happens on many different websites so I don't believe it is a website-specific problem:

[image: Safari hides all fields of a simple date selector]

Is there a way to cause Safari to style the text boxes more reasonably?

UPDATE: Previously I wrote that things display properly in Chrome - they don't. The UI changed once I interacted with it and it showed the same behavior. So the problem is not safari-specific.

Comment: That looks to me like a case of the coder assuming everybody is using IE/Edge & failing to check it on anything else. Safari is using the CSS they specified. Chrome is using a default instead. That, imo, makes Chrome 'wrong' even though the display is accidentally readable.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: I am also wondering if perhaps the web site is assuming a smaller font than is displayed (if the user is specifying a larger font). I generally have to specify a larger font just because my eyesight sucks. What if you decrease zoom (command - minus) do the full words show up?

Comment: Update: Chrome actually showed the same behavior once I started interacting with the UI.  So it is not safari-specific problem as I initially thought. But it is still a problem I encounter frequently.